# How to merge rows in one column to match non-empty rows in the other column?

Tags: r, csv, text

I have a .csv file with two columns. The first one is the ID, and the second one is a text field. However, the texts in the text fields are split into sentences that run over to another row, so the file looks like this:

```
ID TEXT
TXT_1 This is the first sentence
NA This is the second sentence
NA This is the third sentence
TXT_2 This is the first sentence of the second text
NA This is the second sentence of the second text
```

What I would like to do is to merge the text fields so that it'd look like this:

```
ID TEXT
TXT_1 This is the first sentence This is the second sentence This is the third sentence
TXT_2 This is the first sentence of the second text This is the second sentence of the second text
```

Is there an easy solution to do that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping variable based on the non-NA elements in 'ID' and `paste` the 'TEXT' together

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Grp = cumsum(!is.na(ID))) %>% 
    summarise(ID = ID[!is.na(ID)], TEXT = paste(TEXT, collapse = ' ')) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-Grp)  
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID                                                                                         TEXT
#    <chr>                                                                                        <chr>
#1 TXT_1            This is the first sentence This is the second sentence This is the third sentence
#2 TXT_2 This is the first sentence of the second text This is the second sentence of the second text
```

---

Or as @Jaap suggested

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID = zoo::na.locf(ID)) %>%
   summarise(TEXT = paste(TEXT, collapse = ' '))
```

Comment: Or: `df1 %>% group_by(ID = zoo::na.locf(ID)) %>% summarise(TEXT = paste(TEXT, collapse = ' '))`